# Loop in C for Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I have a loop that is meant to write out text on an LCD display on the Arduino. The problem is that the loop can be broken depending on when I send the text over the serial port.

For example, it may read what I want it to write as how I want the text aligned. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is an example of what the loop looks like:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        do {
            ch = Serial.read();
        } while (ch = 'y');
    }

    if (Serial.available()) {
        do {
            ch = Serial.read();
        } while (ch = 'x');
    }
}
```

Comment: is Serial.read() the only task that you do?

Comment: Thats what begins every if statement in the loop.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thats just an example of what the code could look like.

Comment: Does your actual code use `... while (ch = 'y')` rather than `... while (ch == `y`)`? As written, neither do-while loop will ever terminate.

Comment: could look like to do what ??

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        do {
            ch = Serial.read();
        } while (ch == 'y');
    }

    if (Serial.available()) {
        do {
            ch = Serial.read();
        } while (ch == 'x');
    }
}
```

here's a tip: Write your if statements backwards, like

```
if(NULL == somevariable){
    //Do this
}
```

Compilers will complain noisily if you forget the second = (you can't set a constant!)

It's an easy mistake to make!